# why does Javascript not have any threads?

Tags: java, javascript, multithreading, swing

I have been working with Java Swing for a good 6 years, and the threading model is a core principle behind how the GUI responds.

My question is, how does a javascript application deal with a responsive application with user events, asynch backend calls, without having threads?

Is this all managed by the browser? Ie. does the browser manage something similar to an Event Dispatch Thread?

Comment: Did you made some research on your own ? Also you can use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` to make an async behavior

Comment: Don't forget _WebWorkers_!

Answer (score 1):

> JavaScript can only execute one block of code at a time due to its
>   single-threaded nature, each of these units of execution is blocking
>   the progress of other asynchronous events. This means that when an
>   asynchronous event occurs (like a mouse click, a timer firing, or even
>   the completion of an XMLH ttpRequest), it gets queued up to be
>   executed when the thread next frees up. How this queuing actually
>   occurs varies from browser to browser, so consider this to be a
>   simplification, but one that’s close enough for us to understand the
>   concepts. The important concept to take away from all of this is that,
>   because JavaScript is single-threaded, only one unit of execution can
>   ever be running at a given time, and that we can never be certain that
>   timer handlers will execute exactly when we expect.

For example, if we have following script

```
alert("something");

setInterval(function(){
    alert("TIME");
},2000);
```

and we stay on `alert` more than 2 seconds ( which is specified in setInterval function ), execution actions will be queued up and be executed after `alert` will be released

**NOTE:** Because of single-threading in JavaScript we can't rely completely on `setTimeout` and `setInterval` functions